# My VBA code won't work beyond row 790, why would that be?

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a code to organize some data for work, and it works pretty well so far. It copies information from one workbook that I download to our records workbook, and it does that perfectly. Until I reach row 790.  I have two integers I use, iloop and iloop2. iloop is for my downloaded copy, and as far as I can tell, it works fine. iloop2 though, as soon as it hits 790, it keeps counting, but I no longer get the information copied to my record workbook. It makes no sense to me why that is happening, and I was wondering if anyone could help. If you can, and if you share code to fix it, please include pseudocode so I can understand it better and understand it in the future as well. I've included an image of the worksheets as well, just in case.

[Stopping at row 790](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA1By.png)

```
Public Sub Checker()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim iloop As Integer                'Created variable iloop as an integer
Dim iloop2 As Integer               'Created variable iloop2 as an integer
Dim lines As Integer                'Created variable lines as an integer
Dim wb As Workbook                  'Creates variable wb - Source, or Book1
Dim MC As Workbook                  'Creates variable MC - Master Copy
Dim celltxt As String               'Creates string variable
Dim celltx As String                'Creates string variable
Dim LastCell As Range               'Creates Range Variable for pasting in new orders
Dim LastCellColRef As Long          'Creates Long Variable for saying which column to check

lines = 1
Set MC = Workbooks("Master Final SOs Testing")      'Sets the MC cariable to Master Final SOs Testing
Set wb = Workbooks("Book1 (3)")     'Sets the wb variable to Book1 (3)
iloop = 2                           'Var for Book1
iloop2 = 2                          'Var for MC
LastCellColRef = 2                  'column number to look in when finding last cell
Dim Full As Worksheet
Dim Sandy As Worksheet
Dim Dwight As Worksheet
Dim John As Worksheet
Dim Basket As Worksheet
Dim Rack As Worksheet
Set Full = Sheet1
Set Sandy = Sheet3
Set Dwight = Sheet4
Set John = Sheet5
Set Basket = Sheet6
Set Rack = Sheet7


 'Organize_MC Macro
MC.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Full").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Full").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B12:B2000" _
    ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Full").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("D12:D2000" _
    ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Full").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A11:I2000")
    .header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With 'Sorts MC to work well with wb 'Organize_wb Macro
wb.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B2:B2000" _
    ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("D2:D2000" _
    ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:G2000")
    .header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With 'Sorts wb to work well with MC
'if we get workbook instance then
If Not wb Is Nothing Then           'If wb actually has something, then...
    While wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iloop, 2) <> ""                                  'As long as (iloop, 2) in Book is not empty, then
            If wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iloop, 2) <> MC.Sheets("Full").Cells(iloop2, 2) Then       'If the SOs do not match then
                If wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iloop, 2) > MC.Sheets("Full").Cells(iloop2, 2) Or MC.Sheets("Full").Cells(iloop2, 2) = "SO" Then
                    iloop2 = iloop2 + 1                                 'Add to iloop2 in MC to move to next row
                Else
                    Set LastCell = MC.Sheets("Full").Cells(Rows.Count, LastCellColRef).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)       'Creates LastCell variable to copy data to
                    'MsgBox LastCell.Address
                    wb.Activate             'Activates wb
                    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(iloop, 2).Address(), Cells(iloop, 7).Address()).Select          'Selects a cell in wb
                    Selection.Copy                          'Copies the selected cell
                    LastCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues     'Pastes it into my LastCell location
                    Set LastCell = Nothing                  'Resets LastCell for next run
                    wb.Activate                             'Activates wb
                    If Cells(iloop, 1) <> "Y" Then          'If that cell is not "Y" then
                        MC.Activate                         'Activate MC
                        MC.Sheets("Full").Cells(Rows.Count, LastCellColRef).End(xlUp).Offset(0, -1).Value = "R"         'Set location cell value to R
                        MC.Worksheets("Rack").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = MC.Worksheets("Full").Cells(Rows.Count, LastCellColRef).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0) 'Copies the data from Full to Rack
                        MC.Worksheets("Rack").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = MC.Worksheets("Full").Cells(Rows.Count, LastCellColRef).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) 'Copies the data from Full to Rack
                        MC.Worksheets("Rack").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = MC.Worksheets("Full").Cells(Rows.Count, LastCellColRef).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) 'Copies the data from Full to Rack
                        MC.Worksheets("Rack").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3) = MC.Worksheets("Full").Cells(Rows.Count, LastCellColRef).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4) 'Copies the data from Full to Rack
                        MC.Worksheets("Rack").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4) = MC.Worksheets("Full").Cells(Rows.Count, LastCellColRef).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5) 'Copies the data from Full to Rack
                        'All this copies data then to the Rack sheet
                    Else
                        MC.Activate         'Activate MC
                        MC.Sheets("Full").Cells(Rows.Count, LastCellColRef).End(xlUp).Offset(0, -1).Value = "B"         'Set location cell value to B
                        MC.Worksheets("Basket").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = MC.Worksheets("Full").Cells(Rows.Count, LastCellColRef).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0) 'Copies the data from Full to Basket
                        MC.Worksheets("Basket").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = MC.Worksheets("Full").Cells(Rows.Count, LastCellColRef).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) 'Copies the data from Full to Basket
                        MC.Worksheets("Basket").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = MC.Worksheets("Full").Cells(Rows.Count, LastCellColRef).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) 'Copies the data from Full to Basket
                        MC.Worksheets("Basket").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3) = MC.Worksheets("Full").Cells(Rows.Count, LastCellColRef).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4) 'Copies the data from Full to Basket
                        MC.Worksheets("Basket").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4) = MC.Worksheets("Full").Cells(Rows.Count, LastCellColRef).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5) 'Copies the data from Full to Basket
                        'All this copies data then to the Basket sheet
                    End If
                    iloop = iloop + 1           'Move to next row
                End If
            Else        'This runs if the cell values checked are the same
                'If MC.Cells(iloop2, 2) <> copied() Then
                    'wb.Activate                                         'Else, activate the Scheduled Ship date cell, select it, copy it, then paste it in the right cell in MC
                    'wb.Cells(iloop, 4).Select
                    'wb.Cells(iloop, 4).Copy
                    'MC.Cells(iloop2, 4).PasteSpecial
                    MC.Sheets("Full").Cells(iloop2, 4) = wb.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(iloop, 4)        'Updates the Scheduled Ship Date
                    wb.Activate                                     'Activates wb
                    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iloop, 1).Select      'Selects the first header
                    celltxt = Selection.Text                        'sets the variable to equal the selected cell text
                    MC.Activate                                     'Activates MC
                    MC.Sheets("Full").Cells(iloop2, 1).Select       'Selects the first header
                    celltx = Selection.Text                         'sets the variable to equal the selected cell text
                                            
                    If celltxt = "Y" And celltx = "R" Then          'If the line is Y Packaged, and it was in the rack, change it to be in the basket
                        MC.Sheets("Full").Cells(iloop2, 1).Value = "B"      'Update location to B
                        Set Rng = MC.Sheets("Rack").UsedRange.Find(MC.Sheets("Full").Cells(iloop2, 2).Value)        'Find the value in the rack sheet
                        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then          'If Rng exists, then
                            'MsgBox Rng.Address
                            'MsgBox Rng.Column
                            'MsgBox Rng.Row
                            Worksheets("Rack").Rows(Rng.Row).Delete     'Delete the Rng row
                        End If
                        MC.Worksheets("Basket").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = MC.Worksheets("Full").Cells(iloop2, 2) 'Copies the data from Full to Basket
                        MC.Worksheets("Basket").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = MC.Worksheets("Full").Cells(iloop2, 3) 'Copies the data from Full to Basket
                        MC.Worksheets("Basket").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = MC.Worksheets("Full").Cells(iloop2, 4) 'Copies the data from Full to Basket
                        MC.Worksheets("Basket").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3) = MC.Worksheets("Full").Cells(iloop2, 6) 'Copies the data from Full to Basket
                        MC.Worksheets("Basket").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4) = MC.Worksheets("Full").Cells(iloop2, 7) 'Copies the data from Full to Basket
                        'All this copies over the data to Basket sheet
                    End If
                'End If
                iloop = iloop + 1               'adds 1 to iloop in wb to move to next row
                iloop2 = iloop2 + 1             'adds 1 to iloop2 in MC to move to next row
            End If
        'If MC.Cells(iloop2, 2) = "" Then
        '    wb.Activate
        '    Range(wb.Cells(iloop, 2), wb.Cells(iloop, 7)).Select
        '    Range(wb.Cells(iloop, 2), wb.Cells(iloop, 7)).Copy
        '    Range(MC.Cells(iloop2, 2), MC.Cells(iloop2, 7)).PasteSpecial
        '    wb.Cells(iloop, 1).Select                          'Selects the first header
        '    celltxt = wb.Selection.Text                        'sets the variable to equal the selected cell text
        '    MC.Cells(iloop2, 1).Select                         'Selects the first header
        '    celltx = MC.Selection.Text                         'sets the variable to equal the selected cell text
        '    If wb.InStr(1, celltxt, "Y") > 0 Then              'If the line is Y Packaged, change it to be in the basket
        '        MC.Cells(1, iloop2).Value = "B"
        '    Else
        '        MC.Cells(1, iloop2).Value = "R"                'If not Y Packaged, put it in the rack
        '    End If
        '
        'End If
        'iloop = iloop + 1                                           'Add 1 to iloop to move to next SO in Book
        'iloop2 = 2                                                  'Reset iloop2 to 2 to restart the process
        Stop
    Wend
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

This is the part of the code that uses iloop and iloop2, but if you want to see the rest of the code (it just creates variables and organizes the workbooks), let me know.

Comment: Does Sheet1 contain data past row 780?

Comment: could you include what you expect row 791 to contain, and also show  the raw data that creates row 790 and 791 in your updated workbook

Comment: @Chronocidal Sheet1 contains data all the way to row 805 for this download. Future downloads it may not go so far, or it might go farther. And I forgot to mention that on Sheet1, the data from row 751 is copied to 790 in Full. I had to have some empty rows at the beginning, so they don't quite match up. So row 752 in Sheet1 should show up in row 791 in Full.

Comment: @Kevin See my above comment where I answered your comment as well

Comment: @CDP1802 I had that for when I was testing the rest of the code. Because I was editing it a lot, I didn't want to accidentally make an infinite loop (I had done it once and had to close everything and lost my progress), so I put that in there while I was originally testing

Comment: @CDP1802 Okay, just posted the whole code

Comment: OK I haven't worked all the code out yet but i'm looking hard at this line `wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iloop, 2) > MC.Sheets("Full").Cells(iloop2, 2) Or MC.Sheets("Full").Cells(iloop2, 2) = "SO" Then`. It looks like your code relies on both columns being sorted in order. The rows you add won't be in order so I'm trying to work out if for some reason iLoop2 increments into one of those new rows what happens.

Comment: @CDP1802 Correct, it does. In the beginning of this code, it sorts both sheets. And then the rows I add will not be in complete order, but that is why I have the next line If `wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iloop, 2) > MC.Sheets("Full").Cells(iloop2, 2) Or MC.Sheets("Full").Cells(iloop2, 2) = "SO" Then` which would make it so when iloop2 runs into a new row, that new row will be less than the row to be copied over, so it will just add 1 to iloop 2 and continue to the next row until it finds a row that is less than the row to be copied over. If that makes sense.

Comment: Your last statement within the loop is an unconditional `Stop` that will stop your code at the end of the first iteration.

Comment: @FunThomas Yes, I know. It is not needed anymore, but I needed it at the beginning to make sure that I didn't get stuck in an infinite loop during my original testing

Comment: What are the column B values on the last row of full and sheet1 at the start ?

Comment: @CDP1802 For sheet1 it would be 86782 and for Full it would be 86505

Comment: At the moment I can't see why when the value on sheet 1 > 86505 the iloop2 doesn't increment aĺl the way to the end of the sheet and crash excel. I must be missing something.

Comment: @CDP1802 iloop2 keeps on incrementing until it reaches the highest number it can have as a variable, but it stops copying over the information for some reason. And then when it reaches the highest number it can, it just stops saying it's too high of a number to keep going.

Comment: When the iloop2 reached a blank cell do you want all the records remaining on Sheet1 copying to Master ? Also, when  "cell values checked are the same" the record copied to Basket is the last one on the Master sheet eg `MC.Worksheets("Basket").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = MC.Worksheets("Full").Cells(Rows.Count, LastCellColRef).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0)` Are you sure that is correct ?

Comment: @CDP1802 Yes, I would like it to copy over the remaining records over from Sheet1 to Master. And thank you for catching that! That could have not gone well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your specific dataset it is difficult to identify exactly why the loop stops at row 790. However, there are situations at the end of the master sheet where iLoop2 will increment to the end of the sheet (>1 million rows) and eventually raise an error.

I have refactored your code keeping the same basic steps but with protection against an endless loop by restricting the master sheet iterations to the original records only, not revisiting the added rows or moving past the end record.

```vb
Option Explicit

Const DBUG = False ' True/False debug messages

Sub Checker_Test()
    
    Const WB_FULL = "Master Final SOs Testing"
    Const HDR_WS = 1 ' header row
    Const HDR_FULL = 11 ' header row

    Dim wb As Workbook, wbFull As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsFull As Worksheet
    Dim wsBasket As Worksheet, wsRack As Worksheet
    Dim isPackaged As Boolean, locn As String
    Dim n As Long, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
   
    Set wb = Workbooks("Book1 (3)")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    'sort sheet
    Call SortWs(ws, HDR_WS, "G") ' sheet, header row, last col
   
    Set wbFull = Workbooks(WB_FULL)
    With wbFull
        Set wsFull = .Sheets("Full")
        Set wsRack = .Sheets("Rack")
        Set wsBasket = .Sheets("Basket")
    End With
    Call SortWs(wsFull, HDR_FULL, "I")
   
    Dim rng1 As Range, rngFull As Range, lastFull As Long
    Set rng1 = ws.Cells(HDR_WS + 1, "B")
    With wsFull
        Set rngFull = .Cells(HDR_FULL + 1, "B")
        lastFull = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        If DBUG Then Debug.Print "lastFull=" & lastFull, .Cells(lastFull, "B")
    End With
    
    ' scan down both sheet matching SO numbers
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While rng1.Value2 <> ""
        If DBUG Then Debug.Print "DoWhile", rng1.Row, rng1.Value2, rngFull.Row, rngFull.Value2
        ' is this packaged
        isPackaged = (UCase(rng1.Offset(, -1)) = "Y") ' Y = true
        
        If rng1.Value2 > rngFull.Value2 Or rngFull = "SO" Then
            ' move down Full to next SO
            Set rngFull = rngFull.Offset(1)
        ElseIf rng1.Value2 < rngFull.Value2 Then
            'copy record to Full
            locn = IIf(isPackaged, "B", "R")
            Call AddToFull(rng1, wsFull, locn)
            n = n + 1
            
            ' add to basket if packaged otherwise to rack
            If isPackaged Then
                 Call AddTo(rng1, wsBasket)
            Else
                 Call AddTo(rng1, wsRack)
            End If
            
            ' move down Sheet1 to next SO
            Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(1)
        Else
            ' matched - update Scheduled Ship date
            wsFull.Cells(rngFull.Row, "D") = ws.Cells(rng1.Row, "D")
            locn = rngFull.Offset(, -1) ' (R)ack or (B)asket
            
            ' if packaged and racked add to basket, delete from rack
            If isPackaged And locn = "R" Then
                rngFull.Offset(, -1) = "B" ' update locn to Basket
                Call DeleteFromRack(rngFull, wsRack)
                Call AddTo(rng1, wsBasket)
            End If
        
            'move down Full and Sheet1
            Set rngFull = rngFull.Offset(1)
            Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(1)
        End If
        
        ' Exit if last of Full
        If rngFull.Row > lastFull Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    
    ' copy any remaining on Sheet1 to Full
    Do While rng1.Value2 <> ""
       isPackaged = (UCase(rng1.Offset(, -1)) = "Y") ' Y = true
       locn = IIf(isPackaged, "B", "R")
       Call AddToFull(rng1, wsFull, locn)
       n = n + 1
       Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(1)
    Loop
    ' sort
    Call SortWs(wsFull, HDR_FULL, "I")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox n & " rows added to Master", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
End Sub

Sub DeleteFromRack(rng, ws)
    Dim fnd As Range
    ' search for so in rack and if exists delete
    Set fnd = ws.UsedRange.Find(rng.Value2)
    If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
        fnd.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    If DBUG Then Debug.Print "DeleteFromRack", rng.Address, rng.Value2, ws.Name
End Sub

Sub AddToFull(rng1 As Range, ws As Worksheet, locn As String)
    Dim rng As Range
    ' add below last row
    Set rng = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    rng.Offset(, -1).Value2 = locn
    rng.Resize(, 6).Value2 = rng1.Resize(, 6).Value2
    If DBUG Then Debug.Print "AddToFull", rng1.Address, rng1.Value2, ws.Name, locn
End Sub

Sub AddTo(rng1 As Range, ws As Worksheet)
    Dim rng As Range
    ' add below last row
    Set rng = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    With rng
        .Offset(, -1).Value2 = rng1.Offset(, 0).Value2
        .Offset(, 0).Value2 = rng1.Offset(, 1).Value2
        .Offset(, 1).Value2 = rng1.Offset(, 2).Value2
        .Offset(, 2).Value2 = rng1.Offset(, 4).Value2
        .Offset(, 3).Value2 = rng1.Offset(, 5).Value2
    End With
    If DBUG Then Debug.Print "AddTo", rng1.Address, rng1.Value2, ws.Name
End Sub

Sub SortWs(ws As Worksheet, hdr As Long, col As String)
    Dim lastrow
     ' sort by SO and ShipDate
    lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    With ws.Sort
        With .SortFields
             .Clear
             .Add Key:=Range("B" & hdr), _
               SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
               DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Range("D" & hdr), _
               SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
               DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        .SetRange Range("A" & hdr & ":" & col & lastrow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ws.Activate
    ws.Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much @CDP1802 ! I will try that and see how it works, but it looks like it should. And I just ran through my code this morning and tested it, and it looks like as soon as the original records are done being checked, it doesn't add anymore. So it goes through, adds new rows when needed, and after it gets through the original rows, that's when it seems to stop copying rows over. But I hope your code works, so I'll test it out next!

Comment: I just tried the code, and it worked like a charm!! Thank you!!